# sqlite CHECK constraint on multiple rows

Tags: sqlite

If I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (a, b));
```

Can I enforce a column constraint where for all `a` of the same value (`1` for example), `c` can be `NOT NULL` maximum one time.  For example:

```
a  b  c
__________
1  2  NULL
1  3  NULL
1  4  1
1  5  NULL
2  4  1
2  5  NULL
```

would be permissible because for all `a` that are `1`, there is only one `NON NULL` `c`.  However:

```
a  b  c
__________
1  2  2
1  3  NULL
1  4  1
1  5  NULL
2  4  1
2  5  NULL
```

would not be permissible as there are two `NOT NULL` values in `c` for an `a` of `1`.

I've been reading over the documentation for `CHECK` but I'm not sure how to express this in SQLite or if this can be expressed...

Answer (score 4):

To check the other rows, you need a subquery. The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) says:

> The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.

You could do this with a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_one_c_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.c IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'another row has non-NULL c')
  FROM foo
  WHERE a = NEW.a
    AND b = NEW.b
    AND c IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

(And a similar trigger for UPDATE.)